# programmatically make textblock with hyperlink in between text

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, textblock

In XAML I have the following code:

```
    <Label Width="120" Height="20" Name="label1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            click
            <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" NavigateUri="foo">here</Hyperlink>
            please
        </TextBlock>
    </Label>
```

Now I'd like to get rid of the whole TextBlock XAML and add that bit programmatically. I have no trouble creating the TextBlock, setting the Text property to 'click please' and adding a Hyperlink to `TextBlock.Content`. But how do I position the Hyperlink in between 'click' and 'please'? And how do I set the text of the hyperlink to 'here'?

I haven't got much going, so far all I got is this:

```
    label2.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "click please" };
    //(label2.Content as TextBlock).Content does not exist?
    //and even if it does.. how do I squeeze the hyperlink in between the text?
```

Comment: do you have any code you've tried already to work with?

Comment: I added what I have but it's not much..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the code to add a `TextBlock` with a clickable link in the middle :

```
Run run1 = new Run("click ");
Run run2 = new Run(" Please");
Run run3 = new Run("here.");

Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(run3)
                       {
                           NavigateUri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com")
                       };
hyperlink.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(hyperlink_RequestNavigate); //to be implemented
textBlock1.Inlines.Clear();
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(run1);
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(run2);
```

Comment: almost, but this concatenates all the inlines, spacing is not preserved

Comment: @mtijn I added a space after click and before Please. It should work as expected now

Comment: I'm still left wondering though.. how come the XAML code inserted spaces automatically whereas programmatically you have to be specific?? should I raise this as a separate question?

Comment: You should raise the question as to whether you should raise this as a separate question as a separate question.