# Show text in TextBlock in DataGrid as HhiperLink

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, textblock

I have in my project message on the Log:

> Error in object wiht id=[{488DB9A2-6C4C-4E06-887E-6D35C6D538CA}](http://localhost)

And I want to show this guid as Hyperlink as you see. I made creating TextBlock with simple text and link.

```
public TextBlock InitTextBlock(string message)
    {
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        var strs = ParseByGuid(Message);

        foreach (var str in strs)
        {
            var run = new Run(str.Text);
            if (str.IsLink)
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Hyperlink(run));
            else
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }
        return textBlock;
    }
```

But I need put it TextBlock in DataGrid or may be another control.

Comment: Do you want to create a `Hyperlink` control with your custom text and put it inside a cell on a `DataGridView`?

Comment: This question seems to duplicates one of these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890159/programmatically-make-textblock-with-hyperlink-in-between-text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092890/add-hyperlink-to-textblock-wpf

Comment: This question is not like that.

Comment: I want all Guids in a text to show as HiperLink in a DataGridView or DataGrid.

Comment: Or another control like a table.