# Add hyperlink into a string placeholder xaml

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a string I get from the app resources called SupportEmail `"Send an email to {0} to get access"`. I want to add an email hyperlink to the placeholder.

I can do it for a string using the following property that I bind to

```
public string SupportEmail {
get {
 return String.Format(AppResources.SupportEmail, DesiredEmail);
    }
}
```

And xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SupportEmail }" />
```

> Current implementation: Send an email to john@doe.com to get access
>
> Desired implementation: Send an email to [john@doe.com](http://example.com) to get
>   access

How can I achieve this such that the email is a hyperlink?

Comment: usually hyperlink should be displayed in richtextblock control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.blocks(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
<TextBlock>Send an email to 
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="john@doe.com" 
               RequestNavigate="OnNavigate">john@doe.com
    </Hyperlink> 
    to get access
</TextBlock>
```

and in code behind

```
private void OnNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I need to use the appresource string because I support multiple languages @mohit-shrivastava

Comment: See if [programmatically make textblock with hyperlink in between text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7890287/3796048) might help you